# Want to find minimum with NA in vector, but giving me NA instead of number

Tags: r

I'm working on determining final ages based on what two readers have said. I want my code to determine the final ages conditionally: (1) if the two ages are the same, the final age will take on agea, (2) if the two ages differ by one year, the final age will be the lower one, (3) if the two ages differ by two years, the final age will be the average, and (4) if the two ages differ by more than two years, it's a "throwaway."

It's worked for most cases, BUT when I have one age as NA, then it just gives me NA and I want the final age to become whatever the non-NA age is.

This is what my data look like, with commas separating columns:

```
[1] age_a, age_k   
[2] 6, 6  
[3] 8, 7  
[4] 6, 6   
[5] 10, 10  
[6] 6, 7  
[7] 15, 6  
[8] 13, NA
```

Here's my code ("ka_ages" is a vector I created that combined agea and agek for the rowMeans function):

```
ka_final <- case_when(  
agea == agek ~ agea,  
abs(agek - agea) == 1 ~ pmin(agea, agek, na.rm = TRUE),
abs(agek - agea) == 2 ~ rowMeans(ka_ages),  
abs(agek - agea) > 2 ~ NA_real_
)
```

What my data looks like now with the code running:

```
[1] ka_final  
[2] 6
[3] 7
[4] 6
[5] 10
[6] 6
[7] NA
[8] NA
```

So, [7] is what I want it to be, but [8] is not - I want it to take on the number, not the NA. Is this the right function to use for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `age_k` is `NA` in your last line, all of your comparisons return `NA` and your case statement doesn't return anything (hence `NA`).

You need to add a clause along the lines of

```
sum(is.na(c(agek, agea)))>0 ~ min(agek, agea, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Final case statement:

```
ka_final <- case_when(  
            agea == agek ~ agea,  
            abs(agek - agea) == 1 ~ pmin(agea, agek, na.rm = TRUE),
            abs(agek - agea) == 2 ~ rowMeans(df),  
            abs(agek - agea) > 2 ~ NA_real_,
            sum(is.na(c(agek, agea)))>0 ~ min(agek, agea, na.rm=TRUE)
)
```

Comment: Thanks!! Subbed out the "max" in the last clause with "pmin" because the "max" gave me the maximum for the whole vector, not for the two elements.